# Laravel: restore() and update() in one query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

New to laravel, In my case, I have 3 actions (move to active, inactive, and deleted)

- when moved to active/inactive, the `status` column in database is changed,
- when deleted, it gets `soft deleted` (without changing the status column),

Now, when the `deleted` rows are being moved to `active/inactive`, I should use `restore()` and at the same it, update the `status` column as specified.

But I can't find any docs regarding this use case.

Comment: `Model::withTrashed()->find($id)->restore();`

Comment: What is your query?

Answer (score 0):

You may write some helper method for Model to do though

I know this is not exactly the answer of your question but using these you can active/inactive your model without knowing about how it works and also it prevents redundant codes all over the project.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

protected function toggleStatus($status) {
     DB::transaction(function () use($status) {
           $this->restore();
           $this->update(['status' => $status]);
     });
}

public function active() {
      $this->toggleStatus('active');
}

public function inactive() {
      $this->toggleStatus('inactive');
}
```